# How to loop through a list and pass as variable in bash / awk

Tags: bash, awk

**Updated question:**

I have a `config.file` in which I define a few variables that are ultimately called in a different script.

```
$cat config.file

#1 Accession number ref
ref=L41223.2

#2 Accession number SRA
SRA=SRA7361534

#3 Path to SRA 
path_SRA='/Volumes/5TB/sra/'

#4 Path to ref
path_ref='/Volumes/5TB/results/species1/'
```

The #3 (path to SRA) is constant and never changes. For the other variables (`$ref`, `$sra` and `$path_ref`), I would like to read them one-by-one from different fields of an `input.file`:

```
$cat input.file
species1 L41223.2 SRA7361534
species2 D45023.5 SRA9473231
species3 L42823.6 SRA0918881
...
```

All these variables are called several times in a `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Path to the configuration file
. /Users/Main/config.file

# Use NCBI's e-utilities to download reference files
esearch -db nucleotide -query $ref | efetch -format fasta > $path_ref$ref.fasta

# Using NCBI's sratoolkit to download SRA file
prefetch $SRA
cd $path_SRA
mv *.sra $path_ref

# Decompress the SRA file
cd $path_ref; if fastq-dump --split-3 $SRA.sra ; then

echo "SRA file successfully decompressed. Deleting the SRA file now..."
    rm $SRA.sra 
    else
    echo "Could not decompress SRA file"
    fi

# Use bwa to align DNA reads to the reference sequence
cd $path_ref; 
bwa index -p INDEX $ref.fasta
bwa aln -t $core INDEX *_1.fastq > 1.sai
bwa aln -t $core INDEX *_2.fastq > 2.sai
bwa sampe INDEX 1.sai 2.sai *_1.fastq *_2.fastq | samtools view -hq 5 > $SRA.Q5.sam

# Use samtools for conversion
samtools view -bT $ref.fasta $SRA.Q5.sam > $SRA.Q5.bam
samtools sort $SRA.Q5.bam -o $SRA.sorted

# use bedtools for coverage
bedtools genomecov -d -ibam $SRA.sorted.bam > $SRA.gencov.txt

# use awk for extraction
awk '$2 ~ /81|161|97|145/ {print $0}' $SRA.Q5.sam > $SRA.OTW.sam
samtools view -bT $ref.fasta $SRA.OTW.sam > $SRA.OTW.bam
samtools sort $SRA.OTW.bam -o $SRA.OTW.sorted.bam

# Extract FLAG, POS, CIGAR and TLEN for outward-oriented reads
awk '$2 ~ /81|161|97|145/ {print $2, $4, $6, $9}' $SRA.Q5.sam > $SRA.OTW.txt

# Get per-base coverage for outward-oriented reads
bedtools genomecov -d -ibam $SRA.OTW.sorted.bam > $SRA.OTW.gencoverage.txt

# Simplify the output by averaging read coverage over 50 bp window; prints the average count value and last genomic position
awk '{sum+=$3; count++} FNR % 50 == 0 {print $2, (sum/count); count=sum = ""}' $SRA.OTW.gencoverage.txt > $SRA.OTW.50sum.txt

#### End of the script
```

What I would like to do is "read" from the `input.file` into the `config.file`. The first field (species1...) would be used as input for $path_ref, field 2 (L41223.2...) would be used as input for $ref and third field (SRA7361534...) would be used as input for $SRA variable. Once the first round (basically the first line) has been done, the `script.sh` would run again and read fields 1,2 and 3 from the line 2 and so on. Basically, a loop, but somewhat more complicated than the answer below because different variables are called at different places in the script.

This works fine for one variable, however I couldn't implement it with three different variables called throughout the script:

```
while read -r c1 c2 c3; do
  bwa index -p INDEX ${c2}.fasta
  # place rest of your script here
done < input.file
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What would this look like? Like: "Update config.file with the first row of input.file, run script.sh, then the next row of input.file, run script.sh, etc..."?

Comment: Yes, put in a much simpler way than what I wrote. How would you define the ref variable then?

Comment: Add script.sh to your question.

Comment: I added a snipped of a script; basically I call it as a part of another program (bwa) which requires it as input. I just add a suffix (.fasta) to the $ref value.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you for your input. I tried to keep the question more general for others to potentially use as well and perhaps lost some clarity along the way. I updated the question with the actual config.file and the full script.

Comment: Just change script.sh to allow the name of the config file to be passed on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In `script.sh`, after the line `. /Users/Main/config.file`, add these lines:

```
number_of_inputs=$(wc -l < input.file)
for (( i=1 ; i <= number_of_inputs ; i++ )); do
  # extract columns $1, $2, $3 here, from line $i - please change appropriately
  ref=$(     awk "NR==$i{print \$1}" input.file)
  SRA=$(     awk "NR==$i{print \$2}" input.file)
  path_ref=$(awk "NR==$i{print \$3}" input.file)
```

then add a `done` at the end of the file, so the whole thing loops over the values in each line of `input.file`, setting the values accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Your request is a little confusing, but if I understood you, your script has a bunch of code that needs to be executed iteratively with a different sets of values. Sounds like you need a function, or maybe several.

That might look something like this -

```
#!/bin/bash
# load some nonvarying stuff
. /path/to/some/general/config.file
stuff() {
  local path_ref="$1" ref="$2" SRA="$3"
  : run whatever series of commands needed with these ...
  # I'd probably break this into a few function calls,
  # but even one that is most of your current script would do 
}
while read -r path_ref ref SRA
do stuff "$path_ref" "$ref" "$SRA"
done < input.file
```